# Reopening 'hand wave' question on main TeX.SX

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've been looking for a "hand wave" symbol to use in a handout, and I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76345/is-there-a-symbol-for-hand-wave) on the main TeX.SX site. Currently, the question has been closed as a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

As the question is currently written, closing the question makes sense. However, after looking in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List‌](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)​, I was not able to find a satisfactory symbol for this "hand-waving-in-a-proof-or-argument" purpose.

As such, I think the question could be reopened and reworded to ask how one might go about designing or drawing such a symbol, perhaps with `tikz` or `metapost` or whatever. I think such a question would be appropriate under the [fun](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun) tag.

So, I wanted to raise the possibility of reopening this question. Since I'm not able to vote to reopen a question, I thought raising it on meta would be the next best thing. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess there's no universal such symbol? If not, the question might be very open-ended (similar to [matlab2tikz logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132985/5764)).

Comment: @Werner that's true, but is that a bad thing? At the very least, it seems like such a question has a place on the site, with the matlab2tikz logo question serving as a precedent.

Comment: May be ask a new followup Q, If you had some code effort made already on hand-wave and expect to improve with other's idea.